# formik connect props extends missing properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, extends, formik

Looking for a way to avoid writing down in my `Props` all 25++ properties of `formik` when using `connect()`.

The error is exactly this: `Type '{ entry: Entry; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Props': values, errors, touched, isValidating, and 25 more.`

I want to use either the whole `formik` object or the `values` out of it, so something like this:

`const MyComponent = ({ entry, values }: Props) => { //...`

or like that:

`const MyComponent = ({ entry, formik }: Props) => { //...`

while exporting it like that: `export default connect(MyComponent);` (haven't typed that yet, could use some help in this too btw)

and I'm struggling with the types:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  connect,
  FormikProps,
  FormikValues
  ...
} from 'formik';
...

interface Props extends Pick<FormikProps<FormikValues>, 'values'> {
  entry: Entry;
  values: Pick<FormikProps<FormikValues>, 'values'>;
  // values: FormikValues; //tryouts
}
```

or even

```
interface Props extends FormikProps<FormikValues> {
  entry: Entry;
  // values: FormikValues;
}
```

or

```
const MyComponent = ({ entry, values }: Props & FormikProps<FormikValues>) => {
```

i don't want to make the `formik` props optional (so the `?` part). But if I do not use the `?` I get the error `Property 'values' (or formik) is missing in type '{ entry: Entry; }' but required in type 'Props'.` 
. But I don't understand that, since all those props are passed via the `connect()` and not from a parent component.

I thought the `extends SomeProps` keyword lets you avoid typing the properties from `SomeProps` completely. And thus that I don't have to include `formik` or `values` or any of those props in my `Props` interface.

What have I got wrong? How should the types declaration be in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that connect is no longer a part of Formik, please use `useFormik` instead.

You can define it this way.

```js
  interface Props = {
     entry: Entry;
  }

  const MyComponent = ({ entry, values}): Props & FormikProps<FormikValues> => {

  const ConnectedComponent = connect<Props, any>(MyComponent)
```

Now you can easily use `<ConnectedComponent />` without any types errors

Comment: I have refactored my code so many times already that I can't find the component I was referring to in this question. Thanks for your response, I accept it as an answer because it looks legit.